# Update work address

Tags: google-now

I configured my work address and now I can't change it. Sometimes Now shows me: "15 minutes to work" and the route, but it is the old one.
In and older version of Android you could just hold for a sec on location settings, but now you can only enable/disable and see which apps requested permission to my location.

Update: using CyanogenMod 11 (android 4.4.2 KitKat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Google Maps.

Under Settings from Menu select ' Edit Home or Work'

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i needed. Not the first place I'll look at, but makes sense.